# libgdx - How to disable collisions

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx, box2d, collision

So I'm attempting to make a one-way wall, that means my actor can pass throw this object only one side (for example only by the bottom side or the upper one).
I began reading this tutorial: [one-way-walls](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/one-way-walls) 
 but when I try, after checking the direction of my actor, to disable the collision it doesn't work.
I think my issue could by on this part

> Since we will be using BeginContact event which only occurs one time per collision, we can only use SetEnabled once to alter the behavior of the contact. The problem is the contact will revert to being enabled again after each step. We could make a note of which contacts we have disabled and then check the list of them every time in PreSolve, but that is kinda inefficient and more work than I can be bothered with today. Or any day actually :)
>   So we'll just quietly sneak into b2Contact.cpp and comment out the line at the beginning of the Update function which re-enables the contact. After you're done it should look like this: // Re-enable this contact.
>     //m_flags |= e_enabledFlag;

The problem is that I'm using a java version of libgdx in AndroidStudio and I have no idea to how find and change this piece of code.
So I need a way to change it, or a different solution to avoid this collision state "re-enabling" at every cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this in `preSolve` and store the status (if the contact should be enabled or not) in the fixtures `userData`. Of course you should revert this flag in `endContact`.

Comment: The problem with beginContact and endContact is that tey are called only once per contact. So if your actor is touching a wall for half an hour you only get one beginContact call. PreSolve on the other hand is called in every step.